# Finding nil for Firebase key from for loop using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, append

I'm trying to load an empty array so I can push user data to a specific view controller.  The information is being saved in the for loop and loading in the initial view controllers table view.  But where I have `print(self.usersID)` and `print(self.usersnameArray)` below..they're coming back completely empty.  Here is my full query and code....

```
let userRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
        userRef.queryOrderedByPriority().queryLimitedToLast(25).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull
            {
                print("Wait For More Users")
            }
            for items in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            {
                let ids = items.key
                let names = items.value["displayName"] as! String
                let csnames = items.value["caseUsername"] as! String
                let pics = items.value["image"] as! NSString

                self.caseUserNameArray.append(csnames)
                self.usersID.append(ids as! String)
                self.usernameArray.append(names)
                self.photos.append(pics)
            }
            self.friendsTBLVW.reloadData()
        })
        print(self.usersID)
        print(self.usernameArray)
```

Any ideas hot I can get my array appends to persist?

Answer (score 1):

The method runs in the background, so it returns immediately, and your print statements execute before the arrays are populated. You need to move them inside the block:

```
let userRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
        userRef.queryOrderedByPriority().queryLimitedToLast(25).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull
            {
                print("Wait For More Users")
            }
            for items in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            {
                let ids = items.key
                let names = items.value["displayName"] as! String
                let csnames = items.value["caseUsername"] as! String
                let pics = items.value["image"] as! NSString

                self.caseUserNameArray.append(csnames)
                self.usersID.append(ids as! String)
                self.usernameArray.append(names)
                self.photos.append(pics)
            }
            self.friendsTBLVW.reloadData()
            print(self.usersID)
            print(self.usernameArray)
    })
```

And, by the way, reloadData updates the UI, so it must be run on the main thread. For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.friendsTBLVW.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Yeah I got them to successfully print inside the block.  They are ultimately not saving to the public arrays `usersID` and `usernameArray` or the others.  The question was....how can I get them to save publicly so I can place them in prepareForSegue and move this info to another view controller.

Comment: If you're printing `self.usersID` successfully inside the block, but it's empty outside the block, it probably means you're accessing them outside the block before the block has finished.

Comment: Yeah, Michael, what do you suggest doing?

Comment: If you're fetching this data independently of the segue, you need to either not allow the segue to occur until the query is finished, or allow it to occur (with empty arrays) and after your reloadData, call a function on the destination controller so it can refresh (now with non-empty arrays). Alternatively, if this code is part of `prepareForSegue`, you could get rid of the automatic segue and segue manually when the query is finished using `peformSegue` (although this would probably appear laggy).

Comment: I'm really thinking its a "for loop" problem or Firebase query issue.  Even when I try to reload my table view outside the for loop that doesn't work.  Does anyone have any idea why my info is disappearing outside the brackets?

Comment: Something to consider?....Should this be in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, e.g.  ? Would this matter?  Which would work best?

Comment: Normally `viewDidLoad`. The other methods run more often than you need (eg. when unwinding a segue back to this VC, or going from background to foreground).